# Docker container containing a shell script requiring user input and manipulating the network interfaces of the host

Tags: linux, shell, docker

I have a simple shell script which is generating delay, jitter, packet loss using the tc-netem package. You can check the script  [here](https://github.com/stoyanovgeorge/netsim). My idea is that I want to put it into a container and to execute it on my host using an alias. Something like: `echo "alias netsim="sudo docker run -v=`pwd`:/home/netsim/ docker-image"" >> ~/.bashrc` and then when I run netsim on my host to ask me for all the user input. Also the container should control the host network interfaces and I am not even sure if this is possible. My Dockerfile so far is the following:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

WORKDIR /home/netsim

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

COPY netsim.sh random_netsim.sh /home/netsim/

CMD chmod +x /home/netsim/netsim.sh && chmod +x /home/netsim/random_netsim.sh
```

The reason why I want to do it is because my host is running Ubuntu 18.04 and in the tc-netem version there is a bug with the jitter generation. I was thinking that it would be pretty cool if I can use containers to do the same, without re-compiling/downgrading the tc-netem version.

Comment: If you really can't fix the host libraries, and you don't want any of the isolation Docker provides, a chroot environment might be what you're looking for.